# How can I read data in an uncommitted delete?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, transactions, isolation, locks

A MS SQL 2008 procedure deletes then inserts data.  I need to be able to read data in another connection right up until the insert happens, i.e., after the delete.  How can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only isolation level I can think of where you can freely read deleted rows, and not be blocking deletes and inserts, would be [snapshot isolation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tcbchxcb%28v=vs.80%29.aspx). But you'd have had to have opened your transaction before the deletes occurred.

Comment: you would hope that the delete/insert would itself be in a transaction, so either you'd see the original rows or the replacement, but not the work-in-progress...